# Copy values from one list to another without altering the reference in python

Tags: python

In python objects such as lists are passed by reference. Assignment with the `=` operator assigns by reference. So this function:

```
def modify_list(A):
    A = [1,2,3,4]
```

Takes a reference to list and labels it A, but then sets the local variable A to a new reference; the list passed by the calling scope is not modified.

```
test = []
modify_list(test)
print(test)
```

prints `[]`

However I could do this:

```
def modify_list(A):
    A += [1,2,3,4]

test = []
modify_list(test)
print(test)
```

Prints `[1,2,3,4]`

How can I assign a list passed by reference to contain the values of another list? What I am looking for is something functionally equivelant to the following, but simpler:

```
def modify_list(A):
    list_values = [1,2,3,4]
    for i in range(min(len(A), len(list_values))):
        A[i] = list_values[i]

    for i in range(len(list_values), len(A)):
        del A[i]

    for i in range(len(A), len(list_values)):
        A += [list_values[i]]
```

And yes, I know that this is not a good way to do `<whatever I want to do>`, I am just asking out of curiosity not necessity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

```
>>> def mod_list(A, new_A):
...    A[:]=new_A
... 
>>> liA=[1,2,3]
>>> new=[3,4,5,6,7]
>>> mod_list(liA, new)
>>> liA
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use:

```
def modify_list(A):
    A[::] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the contents of a list with another list (or an arbitrary iterable), you can use the slice-assignment syntax:

```
A = B = [1,2,3]
A[:] = [4,5,6,7]
print(A)          # [4,5,6,7]
print(A is B)     # True
```

Slice assignment is implemented on most of the mutable built-in types. The above assignment is essentially the same the following:

```
A.__setitem__(slice(None, None, None), [4,5,6,7])
```

So the same magic function (`__setitem__`) is called when a regular item assignment happens, only that the item index is now a `slice` object, which represents the item range to be overwritten. Based on this example you can even support slice assignment in your own types.